# how can i push data outside web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I want to push data outside web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction what is the correct way to do something like this:

```
let somearray = [];

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x'+transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
            .on('transactionHash',function(hash){
               console.log("thash: " + hash);
            }).on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber) => {

              console.log('transferToReceiver confirmation: ' + confirmationNumber);
              if(confirmationNumber == 1){

                somearray.push("Transaction Confirmed");

              }

            });
console.log(somearray[0]);
```

Comment: This seems to just be confusion over how asynchronous programming works. Your last line runs _before_ the `sendSignedTransaction` event handlers.

Comment: how can i run it after then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with asynchronous programming in Javascript.

You could define a function for sending the signed transaction and call a callback function when you receive the transaction confirmation.

```
function sendSignedTransaction(rawTx, callback) {
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTx)
        .on('transactionHash', (transactionHash) => {
            console.log("TX Hash: " + transactionHash);
        })
        .on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber) => {
            if(confirmationNumber == 1){
                callback("Transaction Confirmed");
            }
        })
        .on('error', console.error);
}

let somearray = [];
sendSignedTransaction(raw, function(confirmedMessage) {
    somearray.push(confirmedMessage);
    console.log(somearray[0]);
});
```

You could also accomplish the same utilizing [`async`/`await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) instead of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

`how can i run it after then ?`
In these cases you can perhaps use some async management, like a promise for example, because the usage of global variables is not a best practice:

```
function Transaction() {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     let somearray = [];

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x'+transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
        .on('transactionHash',function(hash){
           console.log("thash: " + hash);
        }).on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber) => {

        console.log('transferToReceiver confirmation: ' + confirmationNumber);
          if(confirmationNumber == 1){
            somearray.push("Transaction Confirmed");
            resolve(somearray)
          }

        });
  });

}

Transaction().then(result => { console.log('results:', result[0]); });
```

You can even implement it with async/await if you want to assign it like:

```
const results = await Transaction();
```

wrapping this code in an async block